# Using nameof at anonymous type for combobox

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Currently for my `combobox` binding, I write as such:

```
        comboBox1.DataSource = DataList
.Select(x => new { Value = x, Display = x.ToString() })
.ToList();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember =  "Display";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

I am using anonymous type to create a new type for `comboBox1.DataSource`, and then specify the properties to bind for `comboBox1.DisplayMember` and `comboBox1.ValueMember`.

What I don't like about this approach is that I will have to hardcode the property name ( eg: "Display" and "Value"), I would rather use `nameof` or something, *anything*, that can guarantee compile time failure ( instead of runtime) should I mistype.

Is there anyway that I can use `nameof` at anonymous type?

And of course, I don't want to create a class for just this purpose ( too wasteful in my opinion).

Comment: You can use standard reflection.

Comment: @Enigmativity, which is? IMO reflection will involve more hardcoding of property name

Comment: Reflection should be the opposite of hard-coding. Why do you think it'll be the other way around?

Comment: @Enigmativity, saw your answer, not sure it really answers anything

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to use `var x = DataList.Select.....; DisplayMember = nameof(x[0].Display);`?

Comment: @Graviton - Sorry, missed the compile-time requirement.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, that is not always bullet-proof because `x[0]` can be a null when the time `DisplayMember` is set

Comment: @Graviton: That's a separate issue. You still get compile-time property name checks, which is what this question is all about.

Comment: @Graviton: If you mean you're worried that nameof(x[0].Display) will fail because x[0] is null, it won't. It's guaranteed to succeed because, again, nameof works at compile time, and the compiler knows that x[0] will always be your anonymous type, and doesn't need an instance to verify that.

Comment: @BoltClock I was also quite sure it will work, but when I tried - it won't compile, because "expression cannot be used in argument of nameof".

Comment: @Evk: Huh. We all learned something today.

Comment: @Evk Well, it actually says "sub-expression". It's actually logical if you think about how `nameof` works. In my answer, it gets the item before getting `nameof` *and* it checks for null, so you'll be safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. The `DataSource` was your enemy because of it being of type `object`. By the way, are you sure `DataList` is always not null? Consider adding a null check for that.

```
var source = DataList.Select(x => new { Value = x, Display = x.ToString() });
var first = source.FirstOrDefault();

comboBox1.DisplayMember = nameof(first.Display);
comboBox1.ValueMember = nameof(first.Value);
comboBox1.DataSource = source.ToList();
```

Comment: That's good, but you don't actually need to check `if (first != null)`, it will work just fine without. And you don't need to check `source` for null either (with `source?`), since `ToList` cannot return null.

Comment: @Evk Oh, I didn't know that. I just assumed so since it's reference type. Thanks for that. Editing the answer.

Comment: @Evk Actually, if `source` is an empty list, the `FirstOrDefault` will return `null`, so `first` should be checked for null. The other thing is as you said.

Comment: No it doesn't, because nameof will not just extract name from expression, so it will compile like `comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Display"`, there will be no trace of `first.Display` left, and it will not be evaluated at runtime. You can try yourself and see it will not throw any exceptions if first is null.

Comment: @Evk Oh, that's right! I should've seen that. Thanks, I'm just gonna stop from now on and learn to trust you lol.